# How does sync works in a basic level in android?

Tags: android, synchronization

I have been using sync features in my android feature. It stabilizes the data between the local machine and the remote server even when the application is not working in android.

I want to know how in general does the sync works?
Does sync means it stabilizes the data between the remote sever and the local machine in a certain amount of time or when some task is being conducted?

I would love to know about what really happens in sync? I want to know more specifically in account's data sync like the sync in android's google.

Thanks for having a look at my question!

Comment: You need to be MUCH more clear about what you mean by "sync".  Sync is a generic term, we have no idea what technology you mean.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for suggestion. I have explained the question bit more than before. I hope this is okay! Let me know If I need to add some more info!

Comment: Yes it would help if you were specific about what code you are using. I guess you are using the Android Sync APIs e.g. an implementation of `SyncAdapter`? https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters. N.b. the Sync framework is known to have issues because of how background tasks are treated e.g. on some Samsung phones and is not the recommended approach anymore, using `WorkManager` is now recommended & likely to be both more reliable and sustainable on the majority of devices. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager